# Wordpress Tag Cloud Widget - multiple instances parameters issue

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, widget, cloud

I have registered new post type with custom taxonomy on my WP, so now I have two post types (**defaultpt** & **custompt**) and two tag taxonomies (**defaulttax** & **customtax**).

I want to insert two instances of the native **Tag Cloud Widget** on my site:

1. Tag cloud placed on single **defaultpt** post widget area displays tags from **defaulttax**.
2. Tag cloud placed in the footer widget area (same for whole site) displays tags from **customtax**.

When I place Tag cloud widgets on an appropriate widget areas and select desired taxonomy, it displays tag correctly as desired. However, tag cloud is created with default parameters (sort, order, etc.) and I want to change it. These two tag cloud instances should display tags in the same way.

So, I've added a filter a `widget_tag_cloud_args` filter in my `functions.php`:

```
function all_tag_cloud_widget_params() {

$args = array(
    'smallest' => 10, 
    'largest' => 10, 
    'unit' => 'pt', 
    'number' => 40,
    'format' => 'flat', 
    'separator' => "\n", 
    'orderby' => 'count', 
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
return $args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'all_tag_cloud_widget_params' );
```

Now, on my both instances of tag cloud widget displays tags in correct way **but only from defaulttax**. Admin "Taxonomy" widget setting **is ignored**.

Adding parameter:

```
    'taxonomy' => array( 'defaulttax', 'customtax' )
```

forces **both widgets** to display tags **from both taxonomies**.

Adding:

```
     'taxonomy' => ''
```

crashes the widgets.

This filter should use a taxonomy set in the widget settings but after lot of web searching I could not find any solution.

So, my question is: **how to pass a "in-widget selected taxonomy" variable value to this filter**?

Answer (score 0):

Just add parameter where you have registered a custom taxonomy

```
'show_tagcloud' => true
```

Check codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Also you can add condition in filter for change order parameter.

```
function all_tag_cloud_widget_params( $args ) {
   if( !in_array($args['taxonomy'], array('defaulttax', 'customtax')) )  {
      return;
   }
   $args2 = array( ... );
   return $args2;
}
add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'all_tag_cloud_widget_params' );
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) in... I don't understand this logic too :/

Comment: Check code is updated. simple logic, the hooks you have use that filter the one widget args. where it already passed one argument array and it contain current taxonomy selected in widget. you have to pass your array here `$args2 = array( ... );` or you also can change parameters in exiting array $args which comes from hook.

Comment: Jaydip, thanks for your help. I got it now. However, with any conditions applied both tag clouds return tags only from defaulttax!